# Grep - show the whole line when search found with search term of special characters

Tags: grep

I am trying to search in the root folder that contains a bunch of Joomla sites inside subfolders to have a sneak preview of the `public $db` variable of the `configuration.php` file of each site.

Note that the whole `configuration.php` consists of many such variables: 
Sample:

```
public $cache_handler = 'file';
public $cachetime = '15';
public $caching = '0';
public $captcha = '0';
public $cookie_domain = '';
public $cookie_path = '';
public $db = 'database_name';
```

I tried various options with grep, but either I get nothing or grep displays the contents of the whole configuration.php file of each subfolder.

```
grep -F -r "public $db" --include="configuration.php"
```

I suspect it might be related to the special characters in the search term, which somehow aren't treated as should, and grep finally searches for anything that contain "public"
-Whatever the case I need a bit of advise here on how to achieve this.

The final outcome I am after, is to get a list with the configuration.php files of each subfolder alongside with the whole line e.g. "`public $db = 'database_name';`" of text where the `public $db` variable exists.

e.g.

```
/folder1/configuration.php: public $db = "db1";
/folder2/configuration.php: public $db = "db2";
/folder3/configuration.php: public $db = "db3";
```

Comment: that worked mate... obvious things are often overlooked! Thanks!

Comment: @dsstorefile Post that as an answer, please and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shell is parsing the `$db` as a variable and it's probably expanding to nothing. Change the double quotes to single quotes so `grep` gets the literal input.